# Angular : Can't export excel using ExcelJS - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream' - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, export-to-excel, exceljs

I was try to export an excel file using **ExcelJS**

Here is my **console** in VS Code terminal :

```
ERROR in node_modules/exceljs/index.d.ts:1398:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream'.

1398  read(stream: import('stream').Stream): Promise<Workbook>;
                          ~~~~~~~~
node_modules/exceljs/index.d.ts:1424:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream'.

1424  write(stream: import('stream').Stream, options?: Partial<XlsxWriteOptions>): Promise<void>;
                           ~~~~~~~~
node_modules/exceljs/index.d.ts:1511:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream'.

1511  read(stream: import('stream').Stream, options?: Partial<CsvReadOptions>): Promise<Worksheet>;
                          ~~~~~~~~
node_modules/exceljs/index.d.ts:1531:23 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream'.

1531  write(stream: import('stream').Stream, options?: Partial<CsvWriteOptions>): Promise<void>;
                           ~~~~~~~~
node_modules/exceljs/index.d.ts:1828:19 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream'.

1828            stream: import('stream').Stream;
                               ~~~~~~~~
node_modules/exceljs/index.d.ts:1872:34 - error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.

1872             dictionary: Buffer | NodeJS.TypedArray | DataView | ArrayBuffer; // deflate/inflate only, empty dictionary by default                                      ~~~~~~
```

here is **app.component.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->

  <!-- serial must : first jquery then popper then bootstrap -->
  <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->


</head>

<body>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-2">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)='downloadExcel()'>Download as Excel</button>
      </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

here is **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Excel from 'exceljs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'resttest10';

  async downloadExcel() {

    const date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10).split('-').reverse().join('/');
    console.log(date);
    const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('My Sheet');

    worksheet.columns = [
      { header: 'Id', key: 'id', width: 10 },
      { header: 'Name', key: 'name', width: 32 },
      { header: 'D.O.B.', key: 'dob', width: 15, }
    ];

    worksheet.addRow({ id: 1, name: 'John Doe', dob: new Date(1970, 1, 1) });
    worksheet.addRow({ id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe', dob: new Date(1965, 1, 7) });

    // save under export.xlsx
    await workbook.xlsx.writeFile('export.xlsx');

    // load a copy of export.xlsx
    const newWorkbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    await newWorkbook.xlsx.readFile('export.xlsx');

    const newworksheet = newWorkbook.getWorksheet('My Sheet');
    newworksheet.columns = [
      { header: 'Id', key: 'id', width: 10 },
      { header: 'Name', key: 'name', width: 32 },
      { header: 'D.O.B.', key: 'dob', width: 15, }
    ];
    await newworksheet.addRow({ id: 3, name: 'New Guy', dob: new Date(2000, 1, 1) });

    await newWorkbook.xlsx.writeFile('export2.xlsx');

    console.log('File is written');
  }
}
```

I don't get it why it is looking for stream module (and more funny thing - Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS' - I can run all other angular NodeJS projects without error)

Please point out why i can't export excel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't write directly a file on client side. that method is mean to be used on backend side in nodejs. if your expectation is download this file on client side. your code should be like :-

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import * as Excel from "exceljs";
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "resttest10";

  async downloadExcel() {
    const date = new Date()
      .toISOString()
      .slice(0, 10)
      .split("-")
      .reverse()
      .join("/");
    console.log(date);
    const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet("My Sheet");

    worksheet.columns = [
      { header: "Id", key: "id", width: 10 },
      { header: "Name", key: "name", width: 32 },
      { header: "D.O.B.", key: "dob", width: 15 }
    ];

    worksheet.addRow({ id: 1, name: "John Doe", dob: new Date(1970, 1, 1) });
    worksheet.addRow({ id: 2, name: "Jane Doe", dob: new Date(1965, 1, 7) });

    workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((data: any) => {
      console.log("buffer");
      const blob = new Blob([data], {
        type:
          "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
      });
      let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      let a = document.createElement("a");
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
      a.href = url;
      a.download = "export.xlsx";
      a.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      a.remove();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess its better than my version, but it generates a new error

TypeError: a.createWriteStream is not a function
TypeError: a.createWriteStream is not a function
    at e.value (exceljs.min.js:3)
    at AppComponent.<anonymous> (app.component.ts:31)

however, at line 31, 
await workbook.xlsx.writeFile('export.xlsx');

it seems for some reason its not executing

(https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dc83RdDmPJ/)

Comment: i am not using writeFile, did you closely see? I am using writeBuffer. writeFile is only applicable for backend.

Comment: oh i get it now, 
Please edit your answer

remove those lines i guess
    // save under export.xlsx
    await workbook.xlsx.writeFile('export.xlsx');

When I use only writeBuffer , all is fine.

Comment: and please mark it as answer if it resolved your issue.

Comment: could you please inform which version of excelJs you are using?

Comment: @piupaul 3.9.0 exceljs

Comment: @AakashGarg so your above solution is correct. a lof of thanks. But I want to make the above file .csv for a project (not xlsx) . i tried changing your this line to csv a.download = "export.csv"; it says file corrupted then. 
 So How Can I convert the exact above example to csv  ?

Comment: comment or remove the import "*import * as Excel from 'exceljs'*"
Now you can import like this: *import * as Excel from 'exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js';*

Answer (score 24):

In your tsconfig.app.json file add "types": ["node"]

Note, that the "types" are in the compilerOptions section of the tsconfig.

Comment: i did it. no change

Comment: +1 for solving my previous state, now at last angular runs  on the same code, but still can't save files

//core.js:6228 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: a.createWriteStream is not a function
TypeError: a.createWriteStream is not a function//

Answer (score 9):

I found a simple way to resolve this!

comment or remove the import `import * as Excel from 'exceljs'`

Now you can import like this:
`import * as Excel from 'exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js'`

Answer (score 2):

while import the excel : try checking in tsconfig.app.json
where in pre-defined code add "types": ["node"].

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate for an existing anwser.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using angular 8 and below, you need to install excelJs version 1.12.0

see [step by step to use excejs with angular](https://dev.to/ankitprajapati/exporting-data-to-excel-file-in-angular-using-exceljs-k13)